# How to use Kustomize to configure Traefik 2.x IngressRoute (metadata.name, spec.routes[0].services[0].name & spec.routes[0].match = Host() )

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress, kustomize

We have [a EKS cluster running with Traefik deployed in CRD style (full setup on GitHub](https://github.com/jonashackt/tekton-argocd-eks)) and wan't to deploy our app https://gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot with the Kubernetes objects Deployment, Service and IngressRoute (see [configuration repository here](https://gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot-config)). The manifests look like this:

`deployment.yml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: microservice-api-spring-boot
spec:
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: microservice-api-spring-boot
      branch: main
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: microservice-api-spring-boot
        branch: main
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: registry.gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot:c25a74c8f919a72e3f00928917dc4ab2944ab061
          name: microservice-api-spring-boot
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8098
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: gitlab-container-registry
```

`service.yml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: microservice-api-spring-boot
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8098
  selector:
    app: microservice-api-spring-boot
    branch: main
```

`traefik-ingress-route.yml`:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: microservice-api-spring-boot-ingressroute
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`microservice-api-spring-boot-BRANCHNAME.tekton-argocd.de`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: microservice-api-spring-boot
          port: 80
```

We already use [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) and especially the `kustomize` CLI (on a Mac or in GitHub Actions install with `brew install kustomize`) with the following folder structure:

```
├── deployment.yml
├── kustomization.yaml
├── service.yml
└── traefik-ingress-route.yml
```

Our `kustomization.yaml` looks like this:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- deployment.yml
- service.yml
- traefik-ingress-route.yml

images:
- name: registry.gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot
  newTag: foobar

commonLabels:
  branch: foobar

nameSuffix: foobar
```

Now changing the `metadata.name` dynamically to add a suffix to the Deployment's, Service's and IngressRoute's `.metadata.name` from within our GitHub Actions workflow is easy with `kustomize` CLI (because we want the suffix to use a prefixed `-`, we need to use the `-- -barfoo` syntax here):

```
kustomize edit set namesuffix -- -barfoo
```

Check the result with

```
kustomize build .
```

Also changing the `.spec.selector.matchLabels.branch`, `.spec.template.metadata.labels.branch` and `.spec.selector.branch` in the Deployment and Service is no problem:

```
kustomize edit set label branch:barfoo
```

Changing the `.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image` of our Deployment works with:

```
kustomize edit set image registry.gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot:barfoo
```

**But looking into our `IngressRoute` it seems that `.spec.routes[0].services[0].name` and `.spec.routes[0].match = Host()` can't be changed with Kustomize out of the box?! So how can we change both fields without the need for a replacement tooling like yq or even `sed`/ `envsubst`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **1. Change the `IngressRoute`s `.spec.routes[0].services[0].name` with Kustomize**

Changing the `IngressRoute`s `.spec.routes[0].services[0].name` is possible with Kustomize using [a `NameReference` transformer (see docs here)](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/transformerconfigs/README.md#name-reference-transformer) - luckily I found inspiration [in this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/2673). Therefore we need to include the `configurations` keyword in our `kustomize.yaml`:

```
nameSuffix: foobar
configurations:
  # Tie target Service metadata.name to IngressRoute's spec.routes.services.name
  # Once Service name is changed, the IngressRoute referrerd service name will be changed as well.
  - nameReference.yml
```

We also need to add file called `nameReference.yml`:

```
nameReference:
  - kind: Service
    fieldSpecs:
      - kind: IngressRoute
        path: spec/routes/services/name
```

As you can see we tie the Service's `name` to the IngressRoutes `spec/routes/services/name`. Now running

```
kustomize edit set namesuffix barfoo
```

will not only change the `metadata.name` tags of the Deployment, Service and IngressRoute - but also the `.spec.routes[0].services[0].name` of the IngressRoute, since it is now linked to the `metadata.name` of the Service. Note that this only, if both the referrer and the target's have a `name` tag.

### **2. Change a part of the IngressRoutes `.spec.routes[0].match = Host()`**

The second part of the question ask how to change a part of the IngressRoutes `.spec.routes[0].match = Host()`. There's [an open issue in the Kustomize GitHub project](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/4012). Right now Kustomize doesn't support this use case - only writing a custom generator plugin for Kustomize. As this might not be a preferred option, there's another way inspired by [this blog post](https://traefik.io/blog/deploy-traefik-proxy-using-flux-and-gitops/). As we can create yaml files inline in our console using the syntax `cat > ./myyamlfile.yml <<EOF ... EOF` we could also use the inline variable substitution.

So first define the branch name as variable:

```
RULE_HOST_BRANCHNAME=foobar
```

And then use the described syntax to create a `ingressroute-patch.yml` file inline:

```
cat > ./ingressroute-patch.yml <<EOF
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: microservice-api-spring-boot-ingressroute
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(\`microservice-api-spring-boot-$RULE_HOST_BRANCHNAME.tekton-argocd.de\`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: microservice-api-spring-boot
          port: 80

EOF
```

The last step is to use the `ingressroute-patch.yml` file as `patchesStrategicMerge` inside our `kustomization.yaml` like this:

```
patchesStrategicMerge:
  - ingressroute-patch.yml
```

Now running `kustomize build .` should output the correct Deployment, Service and IngressRoute for our setup:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    branch: barfoo
  name: microservice-api-spring-boot-barfoo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8098
  selector:
    app: microservice-api-spring-boot
    branch: barfoo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    branch: barfoo
  name: microservice-api-spring-boot-barfoo
spec:
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: microservice-api-spring-boot
      branch: barfoo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: microservice-api-spring-boot
        branch: barfoo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: registry.gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot:barfoo
        name: microservice-api-spring-boot
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8098
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: gitlab-container-registry
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  labels:
    branch: barfoo
  name: microservice-api-spring-boot-ingressroute-barfoo
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - web
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host(`microservice-api-spring-boot-barfoo.tekton-argocd.de`)
    services:
    - name: microservice-api-spring-boot-barfoo
      port: 80
```

Comment: [vars](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/vars/) seems to be a good feature for this kind of use case. I don't know why this is deprecated.