# Using Kustomize to replace the host in IngressRoute YAML of Traefik

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kustomize, traefik-ingress

I am using [Traefik ingress controller](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/) for my kubernetes cluster.

I have defined a `IngressRoute` of Traefik :

```
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: my-app-route
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - web
  routes:
  - match: Host(``) # I want to fill in the value of host in kustomization.yml 
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: my-app
      port: 8000
```

I am using [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) to manage my k8s manifests.

I would like to replace or fill-in the value of

```
Host(``)
```

to something like:

```
Host(`www.alpha.app.com`)
```

I tried in my `kustomization.yml`:

```
# generate config map for the host value
configMapGenerator:
- name: my-config
  literals:
  - host=www.alpha.app.com

# replace the value
replacements:
- source:
    kind: ConfigMap
    name: my-config
    fieldPath: data.host
  targets:
  - select:
      kind: IngressRoute
      name: my-app-route
    fieldPaths:
    - spec.routes.match
```

I know it won't work since the value contains string ``` Host(``) ```, but that is how far I can make. I want to keep the configMap data as it is, how to replace the ``` Host(``) ``` to `` Host(`www.alpha.app.com`) `` using Kustomize?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that with Kustomize out of the box.

Comment: Note that your target would need to be `spec.routes[0].match` btw.

Comment: I tried `spec.routes[0].match`, but get error `unable to find field "spec.routes[0].match" in replacement target`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know it won't work since the value contains string Host(``),

A possible workaround would be to set a placeholder value in your `IngressRoute` YAML where the host should be. For example, you might use `__HOST_PLACEHOLDER__`:

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: my-app-route
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - web
  routes:
  - match: Host(`__HOST_PLACEHOLDER__`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: my-app
      port: 8000
```

Then use the [`replacements`](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/replacements/) field in your `kustomization.yml` to replace the entire `spec.routes.match` field (which contains the placeholder) with the value from the ConfigMap.

```yaml
configMapGenerator:
- name: my-config
  literals:
  - host=www.alpha.app.com

replacements:
- source:
    kind: ConfigMap
    name: my-config
    fieldPath: data.host
  targets:
  - select:
      kind: IngressRoute
      name: my-app-route
    fieldPaths:
    - spec.routes.match
```

---

Note that [`kubernetes-sigs/kustomize` issue 4012](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/4012) discusses a similar use case, but it is stale (closed by k8s-ci-robot).

The discussion highlights that the `ReplacementTransformer` in Kustomize, at the time of that issue, had limitations when dealing with scenarios where only a part of a field's value (like a placeholder within a string) needs to be replaced. That is precisely the challenge you are facing with replacing `__HOST_PLACEHOLDER__`.

The issue references this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71704024/6309), which could involve defining the `Host` value as a shell variable: That will be used to create the patch file with the correct host value.

```bash
HOST_VALUE="www.alpha.app.com"
```

Then create an `IngressRoute` patch file, which will contain the `IngressRoute` configuration with the host value dynamically inserted.

```bash
cat > ./ingressroute-patch.yml <<EOF
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: my-app-route
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(\`$HOST_VALUE\`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: my-app
          port: 8000
EOF
```

And include the patch in `kustomization.yaml`, to be included as a strategic merge patch to apply the changes.

```yaml
resources:
  - original-ingressroute.yaml  # Include your original IngressRoute resource

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - ingressroute-patch.yml  # That is the patch file we created
```

Kustomize will apply the `ingressroute-patch.yml` as a strategic merge patch to the original `IngressRoute` resource, effectively replacing the host part of the `match` field with the desired value.
However, [`patchesStrategicMerge`](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/patchesstrategicmerge/) is deprecated in Kustomize v5.0.0+, and use the [`patches`](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/patches/) field.

So that would be:

```yaml
resources:
  - original-ingressroute.yaml  # Include your original IngressRoute resource

patches:
  - path: ingressroute-patch.yml
    target:
      group: traefik.io
      version: v1alpha1
      kind: IngressRoute
      name: my-app-route
```

And:

```bash
kustomize build . | kubectl apply -f -
```

That workaround would bypass the limitation of Kustomize regarding partial string replacements within a field. By pre-generating a patch file with the correct host value and including it in the `kustomization.yaml`, you could dynamically set the host in the `IngressRoute`.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out exactly the same solution as your answer.

Comment: @user842225 Great, well done (did you use the second solution, using patches?)